# How to keep a bottom border on bootstrap sticky dropdown header?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My current navbar is a sticky dropdown navbar that will dropdown on a hover rather than a click. I'm trying to have a bottom border on my tabs. It works when the mouse is hovering over the tab, but once the mouse leaves the tab (even to just the dropdown menu items), the bottom border disappears, even though the dropdown menu is still open. All the other hover actions I have on the tabs also go away (I had then text color set to black when hovered over). It makes sense that once the mouse isn't hovering, the changes wouldn't stay there, but the active tag doesn't work, so I'm stuck.

Basically, I want the bottom border to remain while the dropdown menu is open.

[image: What header should look like]

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>ExhibitLab</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropdown, .btn-group").hover(function(){
            var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
            if(dropdownMenu.is(":visible")){
                dropdownMenu.parent().toggleClass("open");
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
</head>


<body>
    <!--Navbar with dropdown menu-->
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:white" role="navigation">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html" style="color:#002873; font-size:35px;font-weight:bold;">ExhibitLab</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size:15px">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Timeline</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Publication</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Additional Sources</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="#contact" class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px"> mail_outline </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#search" class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px">search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu, .btn-group:hover .dropdown-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-menu{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle{
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .navbar .dropdown-toggle, .nav-tabs .dropdown-toggle{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

.navbar-nav a {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar-nav  li.dropdown a{
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  color:#787878;
}

.navbar-nav  li.dropdown a:hover{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #002873;
  color: black !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}


.navbar-nav  ul.dropdown-menu {
  box-shadow:none;
}

.navbar-nav  ul.dropdown-menu  a:hover{
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not targeting the actual `li` and `a` tags properly.

You can simply do this `.navbar-nav li:hover > a {}` and this will keep the `border bottom` active when hovering over the `submenu` items.

Run snippet below and click `Full Page` to see the `menu` item working nicely.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown, .btn-group").hover(function() {
    var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
    if (dropdownMenu.is(":visible")) {
      dropdownMenu.parent().toggleClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu,
  .btn-group:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
  .navbar .dropdown-toggle,
  .nav-tabs .dropdown-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-nav a {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav li.dropdown a {
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  color: #787878;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover>a {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #002873;
  color: black !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-nav ul.dropdown-menu {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-nav ul.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>ExhibitLab</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
</head>


<body>
  <!--Navbar with dropdown menu-->
  <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:white" role="navigation">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html" style="color:#002873; font-size:35px;font-weight:bold;">ExhibitLab</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size:15px">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Timeline</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Publication</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Additional Sources</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#contact" class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px"> mail_outline </a></li>
          <li><a href="#search" class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px">search</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a{
   border-bottom: 5px solid #002873;
}
```